# Close Popover with mapped array HeadlessUI/Next.js

Tags: next.js, tailwind-ui, headless-ui

Cannot figure out how to get popover to close when next Link is clicked inside. Used popover from tailwindui and added next Link, tried the headlessUI closing popover using as={Link}, no luck.

````
                            <div className='max-w-7xl mx-auto grid gap-y-6 px-4 py-6 sm:grid-cols-2 sm:gap-8 sm:px-6 sm:py-8 lg:grid-cols-4 lg:px-8 lg:py-12 xl:py-16'>
                              {about.map((item) => (
                                <Popover.Button key={item.name}>
                                  <Link href={item.href}>
                                    <a
                                      href={item.href}
                                      className='-m-3 p-3 flex flex-col justify-between rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-50'>
                                      <div className='flex md:h-full lg:flex-col'>
                                        <div className='flex-shrink-0'>
                                          <span className='inline-flex items-center justify-center h-10 w-10 rounded-md bg-cyan-500 text-white sm:h-12 sm:w-12'>
                                            <item.icon
                                              className='h-6 w-6'
                                              aria-hidden='true'
                                            />
                                          </span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className='ml-4 md:flex-1 md:flex md:flex-col md:justify-between lg:ml-0 lg:mt-4'>
                                          <div>
                                            <p className='text-base font-medium text-gray-900'>
                                              {item.name}
                                            </p>
                                            <p className='mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500'>
                                              {item.description}
                                            </p>
                                          </div>
                                          <p className='mt-2 text-sm font-medium text-cyan-600 lg:mt-4'>
                                            Learn more
                                            <span aria-hidden='true'>
                                              &rarr;
                                            </span>
                                          </p>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </a>
                                  </Link>
                                </Popover.Button>```


Help please, what am i missing?
````

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this exact issue.

I got it working by doing two things referenced separately in the Headless UI docs. This involved creating a custom wrapper component for Next's `Link` and exposing the `close()` render prop on the Popover Panel.

A minimal example using the solution is listed first followed by an explanation with references to the docs.

### Solution/Example

```
import { forwardRef } from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { Popover } from '@headlessui/react'

const MyLink = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  let { href, children, ...rest } = props
  return (
    <Link href={href}>
      <a ref={ref} {...rest}>
        {children}
      </a>
    </Link>
  )
})

function Example() {
  return (
    <Popover>
      {({ open }) => (
        <>
          <Popover.Button>Open Popover</Popover.Button>
          <Popover.Panel>
            {({ close }) => (
              <MyLink href='/profile' onClick={() => close()}>
                Profile
              </MyLink>
            )}
          </Popover.Panel>
        </>
      )}
    </Popover>
  )
}
```

### Explanation

#### Step 1

Expose the `close()` render prop inside your Popover Panel, per the [alternative solution suggested in the docs](https://headlessui.com/react/popover#closing-popovers-manually).

```
<Popover.Panel>
  {({ close }) => (
```

We will call this in our link to manually close the popup when the link is clicked.

#### Step 2

Create your own custom `MyLink` component (or whatever name you want) that wraps `Link` and forwards props to the child `a` element. As [explained in the Headless UI docs](https://headlessui.com/react/menu#integrating-with-next-js), Next's `Link` component doesn't forward unknown props by default and Headless needs to do this in order to work by adding the necessary event listeners.

```
const MyLink = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  let { href, children, ...rest } = props
  return (
    <Link href={href}>
      <a ref={ref} {...rest}>
        {children}
      </a>
    </Link>
  )
})
```